# Button disabled after one click which opens a URL in a new tab, in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

After I click on the button (green arrow), it launches a url in a new browser tab, which is desired behavior, but button itself becomes disabled. When I right click on the disabled button, then select "Inspect Element", I see:

```
<button disabled="disabled" type="button" class="" title="Go!">
```

It looks like OpenERP adds the attribute "disabled" after the button function "action_go" returns.

Of course, I want my button to stay enabled after the click. How can I do that?

Here is how it looks like on the form:

[image]

Here is the part of xml code where the button is defined:

```
<!-- mrp_bom -->
        <record id="adamson_mrp_bom_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">adamson.mrp.bom.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Components']/field/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='sequence']" position="before" >
                                         <field name="flag_bom_present" invisible="1" />
                                         <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" type="object" readonly="0" string="Go!" icon="gtk-go-forward" name="action_go" 
                     attrs="{'invisible':[('flag_bom_present','=',False)]}"  />
                                </xpath>
```

and here is the button action code:

```
class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    def action_go(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
                bom_obj = self.pool.get('mrp.bom')
                action_obj = self.pool.get('ir.actions.act_window')
                id_s = action_obj.search(cr, uid,  [('name', '=','Bill of Materials' ), ('context', '=','{}' )])
                for rec in action_obj.browse(cr, uid, id_s, context=context):    
                        action = rec.id 
        url = '/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=mrp.bom&action=' + str(action)
        for bom_line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if bom_line.product_id.default_code > '300':
                bom_ids = bom_obj.search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', bom_line.product_id.id)], context=context)
                if bom_ids:
                                        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 
                        'res_model': 'ir.actions.act_url',
                        'url':url % bom_ids[0] , 
                        'nodestroy': True, 
                        'target': 'new'}


        return True
```

Comment: Hi, Did you get a solution for this problem? I have the same requirement. Do let me know if you have already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me in openerp 7.

But:
It's not working if you place the button in a tree. If you place it on a form it's working without "automatic disable".

This is because of a bug fixing:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/openerp-web/+bug/1078157